# Unable to export the output of yolov8

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, yolov8

I trained a yolov8 model on my dataset for a face recognition project, the model is running fine and the prediction of the model is good, but I am unable to export the output of the predicted image.

I have mentioned the code below:

```
# Importing ultralytics library 

from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a pretrained YOLOV8 model

model = YOLO(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\YoloV8\runs\detect\yolov8s_custom3\weights\best.pt")
  
# Use the model to predict, detect and track from live webcam

results = model.track(source="0",show=True)
#print(results)
```

I was expecting that the face/person name detected by the model, to get exported in the csv or excel file. But the output of the model is stored in the array form(results)

Answer (score 0):

```
for r in results:
    # custom handling here
```